# Notation in Modular Arithmetic and AKS Algorithm

Tags: notation, modular-arithmetic

Section $2$ of [AKS-Algorithm paper](https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf) discusses the *Idea* of the Algorithm.

The paper uses the notation in equation $(2)$:
$$(X+a)^n=X^n+a(\text{mod}\enspace X^r-1,n)$$

Does this notation mean $$[((X+a)^n-(X^n+a)\enspace\text{mod}\enspace n)\text{mod}\enspace X^r-1]$$

Also, how does it immediately follows that all primes satisfy the above equation? How can I prove "**Mathematically"** the two lines comments that succeed equation $(2)$ in the above paper?

Comment: Are you aware that this paper is not fully reliable when you see that many errors have been found in a previous version...

Comment: @JeanMarie No. I didn't know. Can you please provide me with latest version and also the reliable links for the algorithm? Thanks.

Comment: My previous remark was maybe not well grounded... forget it. As I am not specialized in this area, I have no alternative to propose you.

Comment: The first dupe explains the notation. Primes satisfy it because the binomial coefficient $\,(p\choose k)$ is divisible by $p$ for $\,1\le k\le p-1\,$ (see 2nd dupe) and because $\,a^p\equiv a\pmod{p}\,$ by Fermat's little theorem.